# sed removes part of the string when doing search/replace

Tags: bash, sed

I have local files containing special characters like square and regular brackets.

When trying to replace part of the filename with SED the filename is being

The original file name looks like this:

- `ddatum - ffirma - bbetreff (wwer) [tags_][Beleg]_007246-1 copy.pdf`

When doing a sed replace I get results like:

- `20161219 - ffirma - bbetreff (wwer) copy.pdf`

another example:

- original: `ddatum - ffirma - bbetreff (wwer) [tags_][Beleg]_007858.pdf`
- result: `20161231 - ffirma - bbetreff (wwer)`

The sed command I use is:

```
 newName=`sed -e 's/ddatum/'\$firstDate'/g' <<< "\$f"`
```

$firstDate contains the simple date string.
$f contains the original file name.

I suppose it has to do the literal characters. My search has not rendered anything useful so far. Thanks for any support.

Comment: Post your actual code, not a secondhand description of it.

Comment: The entire $f string probably isn't making it to sed, so this might be a fair bash issue.  It would be best to have a simple script that reduces it all to that problem.

Comment: Agree with others, $f is likely not what you think it is.  You could also try: newName=`sed -e "s/ddatum/${firstDate}/g" <<< "${f}"`

Answer (score 0):

This will do it:

```
newName=`sed -e "s/ddatum/$firstDate/g" <<< "$f"`
```

**Example:**

```
$ f="ddatum - ffirma - bbetreff (wwer) [tags_][Beleg]_007246-1 copy.pdf"
$ firstDate="20161231"
$ newName=`sed -e "s/ddatum/$firstDate/g" <<< "$f"`
$ echo $newName 
20161231 - ffirma - bbetreff (wwer) [tags_][Beleg]_007246-1 copy.pdf
```